# Compare Dart @override Metadata Reflectee to Instance of _Override

Tags: dart, reflection, annotations, overriding, metadata

I am trying to come up with an example of how we could search for the @override metadata annotation using reflection in Dart.

In the examples I used to learn the dart:mirrors library and reflection, they were always searching for custom made annotations.

[Here is an example where they search for a custom "Todo" annotation](https://www.woolha.com/tutorials/dart-using-and-retrieving-metadata-annotation)

When searching for custom made annotations, they would simply compare the metadata's reflectee to the class data type to check for a match.

In Dart's documentation linked below, you can see an example implementation of an _Override instance.

[Here is Dart documentation on the override constant](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.10.3/dart-core/override-constant.html)

This lead to me to try:

```
if(meta.reflectee is _Override) {
    print('Found!);
}
```

But the "_Override" cannot be resolved and suggest no imports to access such a data instance.

I am able to toString the reflectee for comparison but I feel like it is a dirty solution:

```
if (meta.reflectee.toString() == "Instance of '_Override'") {
    print('Found!');
}
```

When using the @override annotation, I am struggling to find a way to compare the metadata's reflectee to the instance type of _Override.

Here is the Dog class:

```
class Dog extends Animal {
  Dog(String name) : super(name);

  @override
  void makeNoise() {
    print('Bark, bark!');
  }
}
```

Here is my reflection search code:

```
 Dog dog = Dog('Harper');

  InstanceMirror instanceMirror = reflect(dog);
  ClassMirror classMirror = instanceMirror.type;

  classMirror.instanceMembers.forEach((_, member) {

    print(member.owner.simpleName);
    print(member.simpleName);
    print(member.isRegularMethod);

    member.metadata.forEach((meta) {
      print(meta.reflectee);
      if (meta.reflectee is _Override) {
        print('Found!');
      }
      
    });
  });
```

Finally, here is my output when the instanceMembers.forEach loop gets to the method I am interested in:

```
Symbol("Dog")
Symbol("makeNoise")
true
Instance of '_Override'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

```dart
if (meta.reflectee == override) {
  print('Found!);
}
```

or

```dart
if (identical(meta.reflectee, override)) {
  print('Found!);
}
```

Dart constants are canonicalized, and the `override` object (an instance of the private `_Override` class) does not override `operator==` from `Object`, so the two expressions do the same thing.

For annotation classes which have data, you don't know the exact instance, so you have to do type checks. For marker annotations like `override`, which only have one instance, you can compare to the exact constant instance used for annotating.